# Redirecting user from folder to the subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

I have the website (ex. test.com) and another website on the subdomain second.test.com. Users are able to acces this website from www.test.com/second or test.com/second because the folder for this website (second one) is located in the subdirectory of the folder for test.com. I would like to redirect these users (from www.test.com/second or test.com/second) to the subdomain second.test.com.

I have two questions regarding the problem described above:

- Whait the rewrite rule in -.htacess to achieve this
- Which .htacess file I need to edit. The one at test.com or one at second.test.com - for this one, I assume the htaacess from test.com but I don't know what would be the rewrite rule to redirect as I described above.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that your subdomain's document root points to `second` and put something like this into your `.htaccess` in your top level dir (test.com):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^second/(.*)$ http://second.test.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: The code above causes to redirect requests from **test.com/second** to the **second.test.com/second** instead of only **second.test.com**.

Comment: no - only the part of the url after `second/` gets captured

Answer (score 0):

You asked 2 questions. I will answer in opposite order because of their relevance.

1. Place this in `/second/.htaccess`.
2. Use below code.

`/second/.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=second.test.com
RewriteRule ^ http://second.test.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: The code above causes to redirect requests from **test.com/second** to the **second.test.com/second** instead of only **second.test.com**.